# Using sed with command-substitution text in the replacement part is not working

Tags: sed

I have a CFN with cfn-init to deploy a Apache web server with specified virtual hosts. In the template, I use a AWS::CloudFormation::Init configset to replace local IPs with the Instance's private IP.

```
  config:
    packages:...
    files:...
    services:...
    commands:
      replacePrivateIP:
        cwd: "/etc/httpd/conf"
        command: !Sub |
          sed -i 's@127.0.0.1@$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)@g' httpd.conf
```

The sed command works fine outside the CFN template. But in the CFN-init process, it simply replace "127.0.0.1" with the whole $(curl -s http://...) string.

How can I feed the instance private IP correctly into the httpd.conf file through cfn-init?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command-substitution syntax `$(..)` does *not* work when wrapped in single quotes which is as expected in `bash` or most other shells as they preserve the literal value present inside. For your substitution to happen, put it inside double-quotes as

```
sed -i 's@127.0.0.1@'"$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)"'@g' httpd.conf
```

Compare the outputs of `echo '$(date)'` and `echo "$(date)"` for a simple example of your case.